# '80s Sci-fi Anime where galactic explorers search an alien planet for God

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'd watched this sci-fi anime in late '80s. A group of Galactic explorers lands on a planet where they found giant robots, and many other secrets. They were the remnants of an ancient civilization.

At the end they discover a supreme being in the form of a woman. This woman sits on a floating rock, and holds a crystal that holds the secret of all existence of the universe. And she explains that to them...

I can't remember what was... Can anyone help me to remember the name of this anime from the '80s?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  Was it dubbed in English?  Can you describe the look of the giant robots, or point to another anime with similar designs?

Comment: Robots were disabled? Planet was silent? Describe pls space ship of those explorers.

Comment: It's not galactic or space anything, but this description shares a bunch of signifiers with the anime film *Laputa: Castle in the Sky*.

Comment: Sounds a bit similar to the Cobra movie from 1982. And probably a bunch of other movies, too. What else do you remember?